# What should be done when someone posts the answer to their question as part of the question

Tags: discussion, edits, flags

Several times while browsing stack exchange sites, I've noticed that people sometimes edit their question to include the answer to the question as a separate section of the question.

Example (initially posted as a question then edited to include the answer)

> ## How do I do XYZ with ABC?
>
> #### Question
>
> I'm trying to do XYZ with ABC, I've tried... etc
>
> #### Edit: Answer
>
> I found out how to do XYZ with ABC by taking the ...

I would have thought the thing to do upon seeing this would be to edit the question to remove the answer from it and then posting the answer as an answer to the question, but would it be better to flag and let a moderator do it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could

- leave a comment asking the OP to put it in a answer.
- If the OP does not react you can do it yourself.

  - If you mark the answer as *Community Wiki* then you won't get rep from it if you think you don't deserve it.